# Page content turns back to portrait within `landscape` environment

Tags: tables, floats, landscape, lscape

I have some wide tables, so I decided to use landscape orientation to show them. I use the `landscape` environment from the `lscape` package to achieve this. Unfortunately, I am experiencing some strange behavior. Sometimes the page "turns back" to portrait mode. It is hard to give a MWE because you need several floating tables to trigger this. Below I included an example with 4 tables.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[para,flushleft]{threeparttable}%

\begin{document}    
\begin{landscape}%

\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Aggregate ERR-REV regressions}
\label{tab_agg_errrev}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{13}{c}}
\hline\hline
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(9)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(10)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(11)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(12)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(13)}\\
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{GDP}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{HS}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{IP}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{PGDP}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{UE}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{TB3}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{AAA}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{CPI}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{CONS}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{FG}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{SG}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{NRI}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{RI}\\
\hline
Revision            &        0.35\sym{*}  &        0.86\sym{***}&        0.56\sym{***}&        0.73\sym{***}&        0.54\sym{***}&        0.33\sym{**} &        0.08         &        0.48\sym{**} &        0.02         &        0.47\sym{*}  &       -0.07         &        0.76\sym{***}&        0.75\sym{*}  \\
                    &      (0.17)         &      (0.15)         &      (0.14)         &      (0.20)         &      (0.12)         &      (0.13)         &      (0.12)         &      (0.17)         &      (0.20)         &      (0.23)         &      (0.15)         &      (0.23)         &      (0.29)         \\
[1em]
Constant            &       -0.09         &        0.02         &       -0.68         &        0.02         &       -0.03         &       -0.25\sym{***}&       -0.28\sym{***}&       -0.09         &        0.31         &        0.44         &        0.07         &        1.14         &        1.10         \\
                    &      (0.13)         &      (0.01)         &      (0.37)         &      (0.09)         &      (0.03)         &      (0.06)         &      (0.05)         &      (0.10)         &      (0.21)         &      (0.32)         &      (0.10)         &      (0.61)         &      (0.79)         \\
\hline
N                   &         689         &         689         &         689         &         689         &         689         &         490         &         490         &         490         &         490         &         490         &         490         &         490         &         490         \\
R2                  &       0.012         &       0.158         &       0.035         &       0.059         &       0.112         &       0.049         &       0.003         &       0.026         &       0.000         &       0.010         &       0.000         &       0.035         &       0.038         \\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\emph{Notes:} 
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{table}[htbp] \centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Individual pooled ERR-REV regressions}
\label{tab_indpool_errev}

\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{13}{c}}
\hline\hline
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(9)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(10)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(11)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(12)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(13)}\\
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{GDP}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{HS}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{IP}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{PGDP}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{UE}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{TB3}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{AAA}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{CPI}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{CONS}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{FG}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{SG}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{NRI}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{RI}\\
\hline
Revision            &       -0.32\sym{***}&        0.19\sym{***}&       -0.25\sym{***}&       -0.32\sym{***}&        0.24\sym{**} &        0.11         &       -0.15\sym{**} &       -0.20\sym{*}  &       -0.44\sym{***}&       -0.44\sym{***}&       -0.47\sym{***}&       -0.35\sym{***}&       -0.27\sym{***}\\
                    &      (0.04)         &      (0.05)         &      (0.04)         &      (0.04)         &      (0.08)         &      (0.07)         &      (0.05)         &      (0.09)         &      (0.04)         &      (0.04)         &      (0.04)         &      (0.09)         &      (0.05)         \\
[1em]
Constant            &       -0.32         &        0.01         &       -1.11\sym{***}&        0.18         &        0.00         &       -0.31\sym{***}&       -0.29\sym{***}&       -0.14         &        0.25         &        0.40         &       -0.05         &        0.74         &       -0.08         \\
                    &      (0.16)         &      (0.01)         &      (0.32)         &      (0.13)         &      (0.03)         &      (0.06)         &      (0.05)         &      (0.12)         &      (0.14)         &      (0.32)         &      (0.12)         &      (0.64)         &      (0.96)         \\
\hline
N                   &       19382         &       18613         &       18504         &       19199         &       19657         &       12551         &       10921         &       12643         &       12623         &       11829         &       11858         &       12336         &       12355         \\
R2                  &       0.045         &       0.014         &       0.022         &       0.058         &       0.029         &       0.007         &       0.015         &       0.011         &       0.077         &       0.050         &       0.126         &       0.032         &       0.022         \\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
\emph{Notes:} djfkgjkfgjkflgjlfgj
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}%
%\afterpage{\clearpage}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{table}[htbp] \centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Model test: forecaster FE in ERR-REV regressions}
\label{tab_indidFE_errrev}

\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{13}{c}}
\hline\hline
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(9)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(10)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(11)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(12)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(13)}\\
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{GDP}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{HS}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{IP}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{PGDP}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{UE}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{TB3}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{AAA}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{CPI}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{CONS}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{FG}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{SG}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{NRI}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{RI}\\
\hline
Revision            &       -0.33\sym{***}&        0.11\sym{*}  &       -0.26\sym{***}&       -0.36\sym{***}&        0.19\sym{*}  &        0.08         &       -0.19\sym{***}&       -0.26\sym{*}  &       -0.47\sym{***}&       -0.44\sym{***}&       -0.47\sym{***}&       -0.35\sym{***}&       -0.32\sym{***}\\
                    &      (0.04)         &      (0.05)         &      (0.04)         &      (0.03)         &      (0.08)         &      (0.06)         &      (0.04)         &      (0.10)         &      (0.04)         &      (0.04)         &      (0.04)         &      (0.07)         &      (0.05)         \\
\hline
N                   &       19382         &       18613         &       18504         &       19199         &       19657         &       12551         &       10921         &       12643         &       12623         &       11829         &       11858         &       12336         &       12355         \\
R2                  &       0.050         &       0.005         &       0.025         &       0.082         &       0.019         &       0.004         &       0.027         &       0.018         &       0.096         &       0.049         &       0.135         &       0.034         &       0.032         \\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
\emph{Notes:}
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{table}[htbp] \centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Model test: decompose revision in aggregate ERR-REV regression}
\label{tab_agg_seprev}

\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{13}{c}}
\hline\hline
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(9)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(10)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(11)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(12)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(13)}\\
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{GDP}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{HS}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{IP}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{PGDP}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{UE}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{TB3}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{AAA}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{CPI}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{CONS}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{FG}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{SG}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{NRI}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{RI}\\
\hline
fcast               &        0.38\sym{*}  &        0.87\sym{***}&        0.58\sym{***}&        0.75\sym{***}&        0.54\sym{***}&        0.30\sym{*}  &        0.05         &        0.33         &        0.02         &        0.47\sym{*}  &       -0.06         &        0.79\sym{***}&        0.78\sym{**} \\
                    &      (0.17)         &      (0.16)         &      (0.14)         &      (0.20)         &      (0.12)         &      (0.13)         &      (0.11)         &      (0.19)         &      (0.20)         &      (0.19)         &      (0.15)         &      (0.23)         &      (0.30)         \\
[1em]
lfcast              &       -0.55\sym{*}  &       -0.87\sym{***}&       -0.75\sym{***}&       -0.77\sym{***}&       -0.60\sym{***}&       -0.34\sym{*}  &       -0.13         &       -0.65\sym{***}&       -0.02         &        0.21         &        0.39         &       -0.84\sym{**} &       -0.58\sym{*}  \\
                    &      (0.22)         &      (0.17)         &      (0.20)         &      (0.20)         &      (0.12)         &      (0.14)         &      (0.11)         &      (0.18)         &      (0.25)         &      (0.27)         &      (0.22)         &      (0.29)         &      (0.26)         \\
[1em]
Constant            &        0.41         &        0.03         &       -0.07         &        0.13         &        0.30\sym{*}  &       -0.02         &        0.32         &        0.95\sym{***}&        0.22         &       -0.52         &       -0.50\sym{*}  &        1.38         &        0.56         \\
                    &      (0.32)         &      (0.04)         &      (0.49)         &      (0.14)         &      (0.12)         &      (0.12)         &      (0.18)         &      (0.25)         &      (0.38)         &      (0.33)         &      (0.23)         &      (0.86)         &      (0.64)         \\
\hline
$p(\beta_1+\beta_2=0)$   &      0.0793         &      0.8440         &      0.2026         &      0.4726         &      0.0058         &      0.0779         &      0.0024         &      0.0000         &      0.8041         &      0.0000         &      0.0034         &      0.6985         &      0.2439         \\
N                   &         689         &         689         &         689         &         689         &         689         &         490         &         490         &         490         &         490         &         490         &         490         &         490         &         490         \\
R2                  &       0.018         &       0.158         &       0.040         &       0.061         &       0.135         &       0.073         &       0.086         &       0.075         &       0.013         &       0.046         &       0.016         &       0.035         &       0.048         \\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
\emph{Notes:}
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{landscape}%    
\end{document}
```

When I compile the code, the 1st page is landscape, the 2nd is portrait and part of the tables is cut off, and the 3rd page is landscape again. Here is what I get:

[image: Compiled pages]

Comment: are you sure it isn't your pdf reader? some of them have "smart" heuristics to guess when to rotate the view.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I just tested with Adobe reader, 2nd page is really in portrait mode

Comment: `tablenotes` seems to be (one) cause of the problem

Comment: @Andrew - Try a `\clearpage` after the first table.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: it is not the page view in the pdf reader that is rotated, but the content itself. The table itself is not rotated on the 2nd page. @ChristianHupfer: The `tablenotes` is part of the `threeparttable` package, which I think is a fairly standard one. Of course, it can still be part of the problem. @ArashEsbati: I forgot to mention that I tried the `\clearpage`, and it works, but the problem is that it also induces a page break, so you end up with a page with only one of these wide, but short tables. I would prefer some automatic solution, because I have many of these tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
\begin{table}[htb]
```

instead of

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
```

It seems `lscape` doesn't rotate float pages. It's so long ago I can't remember if that's a documented feature or a bug. I'm going to assume the former for now.